# php indicate the real type

Tags: php, types, casting

I would like or I will prefer indicate the real type of a parameter in a function with Php, it's possible ?

Example :

```
<?php
function test($param)
{
   echo $param;
}
$str = "hiiiii everyone";
test($str);
?>
```

Instead of put just $param in the function test; I would like put something like that

```
function test(string $param) // string is the type of the param, that can be int, long ect or an object which I had created.
```

It's possible to do that with the last version of PHP ?

Comment: [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) [is](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) [your](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-string.php) [friend](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-object.php). Read it. Love it. Use it.

Comment: Looked like a child raisin had type the question out, we are grown ups here (I assume (probably wrongfully))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [Type Hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php). However, as stated in the linked manual page:

> Type hints can not be used with scalar types such as int or string.

This means that no, you cannot force the argument for a function to be string. You can force it to be an instance of a specific class, something which is callable, or an array.

If you want to force an argument to be a string, do something like this:

```
function my_func ($mustBeAString) {
  if (!is_string($mustBeAString)) return;
  // Do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Type Hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) was introduced in PHP5. You can now force parameters to be of a certain type by providing that type in the parameter list itself, as your example demonstrated.

Unfortunately, scalar objects (like `int`, and `string`) are not permitted.

You can do your own checking internally to determine whether the passed object is of the proper type using methods like [`gettype()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php), [`is_string()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-string.php) (handle [other types](http://www.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=is_&lang=en&scope=quickref) as well), or even the type operator [`instanceof`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php).

Answer (score 1):

No. PHP is a dynamically typed language; variables (and as such, parameters) don't have set types. You could try and enforce your own thing using [`gettype`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php), ie:

```
function test($param) {
    if(gettype($param) != "string")
        throw new TypeException //or something
}
```

But it's a bad idea. Don't try and implement features from other languages in a language you're new to. Just try and embrace the proper way and see how it goes from there.

Comment: Oops forgot to indent. Thanks @xbonez

Comment: thx it's clear, it's very boring for the beauty of the code to have some functions without knowing their types ....

Comment: Just to add... in PHP, `$Vars = null;` is true for `ìf(!$Vars)`, `if($Vars == null)` and `if($Vars == 0)`. As you can see, null = 0 = empty

Answer (score 0):

I would like to bring this to the table:

```
var_dump($str);
```